# Does function module in ABAP allow inline data declaration

Tags: abap

Is Inline Data declaration possible in the importing parameter of the function module. Currently it is giving 

`The inline declaration "DATA(IT_MARA)" is not possible in this position.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Typechecking in general is really bad on function modules. Just take this snippet for example:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT'
 EXPORTING
   input         = lw_string
   test          = someother
   banana_banana = someother
 IMPORTING
   output        = lw_string.
```

It will trigger a runtime error, but doesn't stop the compilation. Theres only a critical note inside extended program check.

Anyway, inline declarations work on method calls. Most of the old function module code is already translated into OOP.